# Trying to position a span over an input box using CSS

Tags: css

I'm trying to reproduce the input box behavior of stackoverflow where they place span text over an input box.  It looks like the text is actually inside the input box, but is actually just a finely positioned span.  They hide the span when the user types text into the field.  To see the behavior in action, press "Ask Question" and then look at the "Title" input box.  The text says: "what's your programming question?  be specific".

I'm creating this for an ecommerce checkout page, so there will be multiple input boxes of different widths and positions.

As a CSS newbie, is there a way to create input boxes and then somehow attach a span to the left and vertical center of a input field?  I suppose I could go through and position each one individually, so I'm hoping a class could be developed that would automatically attach a span to a previously defined input box.  Does anyone have an elegant way to do this without custom positioning each one?

Comment: Do you want JavaScript code too? Any libraries, such as jQuery available?

Answer (score 1):

I just did this with a [jQuery plugin](https://github.com/alexanderdickson/inputLabel).

I used JavaScript to automate this, but the same rules apply.

Comment: That sounds nice.  I just grabbed the code and am trying to run it. I tried executing it using $('#firstname').inputLabel("First Name"); but it isn't working.  What is the calling convention?

Comment: @user77413 Just use `$('#firstname').inputLabel()`. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/snkJm/). (I uncovered a bug just then, so I fixed the code and pushed it back to GitHub.)

Comment: Thanks!  I want to add some animation to it as well.  I found this: http://fuelyourcoding.com/scripts/infield/ which is exactly what I want, but it seems to restrict you to block level elements and my form is not vertical like theirs.  I'll play around with your code and see if I can implement something similar.  When a user tabs to the field as it is it deletes the tag before they've had a chance to read it.

Comment: @user77413 That's an interesting issue, and I've noticed the Stack Overflow ones do not do this. I'll look into this, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

If you look closely, its not the span that is positioned. There's another hidden `input`.

```
<input type="text" tabindex="100" class="actual-edit-overlay" value="" style=" background-color: white; color: black; opacity: 1; width: 610px; height: 15px; " disabled="">
<input id="title" name="title" type="text" maxlength="300" tabindex="100" class="ask-title-field edit-field-overlayed" value="" style="z-index: 1; position: relative; opacity: 0.3; ">
<span class="edit-field-overlay">what's your programming question? be specific.</span>
```

If you inspect with firebug and set turn off the `display:none;`, you will see clearly the one textbox, another textbox and a span.